# Resigning the app with the Enterprise Deployment via xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I used .xcarchive file and I was unable to install the signed ipa that I generated on an iPad. The signed ipa was derived from the xcode archive for iPad.

I get the following errors:

```
 2 14:58:12 Test-iPad3 installd[34] <Error>: 0x1b1d000 -
[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 186: 
Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle :
path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/
  com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.bFDqhk/extracted/
 Payload/Test_iPad.app identifier = com.companyname.xxx.ipad 
type = 4> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not
permitted by provisioning profile)
Nov  2 14:58:12 Test-iPad3 installd[34] <Error>: 
0x1b1d000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: 
Verification stage failedstat ov: No such file or directory
```

When I use the explicit bundle-identifier com.companyname.xxx.ipad  I get an error

" An App ID with Identifier 'com.companyname.xxx.ipad' is not available. Please enter a different string.”

Any Idea what is the problem?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Your app has some specific entitlements turned on, so you cannot use the wild card profile. The wild card profile is just a catch all with no entitlements to cut out some setup a little in the beginning. To add entitlements, you will need to create an App ID in the member center (your bundle-identifier will need to match this ID) that has the entitlements associated with it. Then you need to create a new provisioning profile that uses this App ID. When you have the new provisioning profile, you can sign/archive your app.

Comment: Thanks, You mean "beta-reports-active", What if I use adhoc profile for . xcarchive ? then can I use the wild card profile for resigning the app with the Enterprise Deployment via xcode?

Comment: Should I have ad-hoc for creating .xcarchive and then use wild card profile profile for re-sign?